# WPF why my ObservableCollection object collection not update my ProgressBar

Tags: wpf, listview, progress-bar

i have `WPF application` and i am using `PcapDotNet DLLs` to send `packets` through the `Networkcard`.

This is my object that represent `Wireshark file`:

```
public class WiresharkFile
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    virtual public void NotifyPropertyChange(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

   private string _file; // file path
   private string _packets; // how many packet in file
   private string _sentPackets; // how many packet sent
   private string _progress; // percentage (_sentPackets/_packets) * 100

   public int Progress
   {
       get { return _progress; }
       set
       {
           _progress = value;
           NotifyPropertyChange("Progress");
       }
   }

   public void Transmit(WireshrkFile)
   {
         // here i am send the packets
   }
}
```

My list that hold this objects:

```
public ObservableCollection<WireshrkFile> files{ get; set; }
```

As you can see in every file that in process i am calculate the `Progress`.

Now all my files is inside `ListView` and in this `ListView` i have `Progress-Bar column`.

This is my Progress-Bar style:

```
<!-- Progress-Bar style -->
<Style x:Key="CustomProgressBar" TargetType="ProgressBar" >
    <Setter Property="Template" >
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ProgressBar">
                <Border BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" Background="LightGray" CornerRadius="0" Padding="0" >
                    <Grid x:Name="PART_Track">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="PART_Indicator" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Fill="#FF15669E" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Progress-Bar definition inside my `ListView`

```
<ListView.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate">
        <Grid Margin="-6">
            <ProgressBar Name="prog" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding Progress}" 
                         Width="{Binding Path=Width, ElementName=ProgressCell}" 
                         Height="20" Margin="0" Background="#FFD3D0D0" Style="{StaticResource CustomProgressBar}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=prog, StringFormat={}{0}%}" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="11" Foreground="Black" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ProgressBarTemplate">
        <Label  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </ControlTemplate>
</ListView.Resources>
```

So when the `Wireshark file` is in process i can see that it send the `packets` and the properties changing but the `Propress-Bar` is still with `0%`.
So i made i little test and inside `timer event click` changed my `WireshakFile` `Progress` property and in this case i can see the my `ListView Progress-Bar` changing.
So my question is what i am doing wrong ?

**Edit:**

I also try something that looks very strange but this is woking:

Inside my `Timer_Tick` i try to loop over my `ObservableCollection` collection:

```
foreach (WiresharkFile item in files)
{
    item.Progress = item.Progress;
}
```

As you can see it only make pointer to the same property but this is working.

Comment: I can see the NotifyPropertyChange method but i don't see the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface ?!

Comment: See my WiresharkFile class update

Comment: Even if the files are inside an ObservableCollection, your WiresharkFile needs to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged so other classes know they can suscribe to its changes. But other than that... This may be a dumb question, but, are you using asynchronous calls? If not, you may be blocking the UI thread, which would make the ProgressBar not update until the task is finished.

Comment: What need to be done in order to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in my class ? BTW i am open this Transmit via Task

Comment: Just this: `public class WiresharkFile : INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: @almulo i already did it, my mistake but this still not working

Comment: Width="{Binding Path=Width, ElementName=ProgressCell}"  whether it is ProgressCell or progress?

Comment: This is the width of my progressbar cell

Comment: Maybe setting the UpdateSourceTrigger  as PropertyChanged for your TextBlock Text property.

Comment: @almulo i am doing the work with different Thread

Comment: I see... The only thing I can think of is inheriting from DependencyObject and making Progress a DependencyProperty, but really seems like an overkill and I'm starting to think it's not a notification issue... Can you verify that the Progress property is indeed changing?

Comment: Can i have code example please ? (i am new with WPF)

Comment: Also please see my edit